# Conceptual Problems in Understanding Thermal Field States in nonrelativistic QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, thermal-field-theory

I have conceptual problems understanding the notion of thermal states in the context of nonrelatistic (cavity) QED. My main problem is the definition of temperature associated to the (quantized) radiation field, since I always tend to think in terms of classical macroscopic thermodynamics pictures, where I have ideal gas particles attributed with a finite mass. I would very much appreciate a hint on how to deal with thermal situations and states (I personally work in the formalism of thermofield dynamics in condensed matter problems) and their physical explanation in the context of QED.

Comment: Quantum statistical mechanics is intuitively easier than classical statistical mechanics. Instead of thinking in terms of complicated particle-motions, we can think in terms of energy eigenstates, with the system confined to the given volume. For the case of pure EM in a box with idealized boundary conditions, we can even relate energy eigenstates to photons. As always, temperature is defined by $1/T = \partial S(E,V)/\partial E$, where $S(E,V)$ is the entropy (number of orthogonal states whose total energy is $\leq E$ and that fit in volume $V$). Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not completely sure whether I actually get your point. I think of a collection of harmonic oscillators, when imagine the quantized radiation field, which may be confined to a box. Does this mean, the temperature is calculated from the entropy related to this set of harmonic oscillators? I am aiming at the study of thermal version of coherent states, number states and squeezed states.

Comment: The entropy function $S(E,V)$ doesn't care which set of orthogonal states we use. It only cares about the number of them, which is the same for any orthogonal basis. Regarding the state, it (almost certainly) maximizes the entropy of the combined system (cavity + bath), at least in equilibrium. This principle leads to a mixed state, like $\exp(-\beta H)$ where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the cavity EM field. This state can be expressed in any basis (harmonic oscillator, coherent states, etc). You seem to be interested in something more specific, though, and cavity QED isn't my specialty.